# Check if name exists using Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How do I check if a name exists using Cloud Functions for Firebase?

I have the following data structure:

[image: screenshot]

And this pseudo-code:

```
exports.addIt = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {

if(creationDate does not exist)
event.data.adminRef.update({"creationDate":Date.now()})

else // do not update anything

})
```

I want to check if 'creationDate' already exists or not. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this :-

```
exports.addIt = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
if(typeof event.data.val().creationDate != 'undefined')
return event.data.adminRef.update({"creationDate":Date.now()})

else // do not update anything

})
```

Comment: You will also want to return the promise that comes from update() in order to ensure that Cloud Functions will not clean up the function before the update is complete.

Comment: Absolutely! Understanding promises is imperative to acing Firebase Cloud Functions. @Jonathan Doe, do check out [Jen Person's Firecasts](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM). They're of great help!

Comment: @RohanStark Please include the `return` in your answer because sometimes Cloud Functions will clean up before the update is complete.